# How to authenticate redis cache in imcache?

Tags: java, caching

I've created an instance of redis cache of [imcache](https://github.com/Cetsoft/imcache) but couldn't find way of doing authentication.

By the way, I can't add imcache tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think imcache currently doesn't support any authentication methods. There's an open issue about it, check it out from the link below.

https://github.com/Cetsoft/imcache/issues/13